# How to suppress info and success messages in sbt?

Tags: scala, sbt

When I do `sbt run` I see some header and footer info which I would like to get rid of:

```
$ sbt run 
[info] Set current project to XXX (in build file:/path/to/dir/)
<actual program output goes here; stuff I care about>
[success] Total time: 68 s, completed Apr 1, 2012 7:30:45 PM
$
```

How can I get rid of those 2 additional lines (i.e., the `[info]` and `[success]` lines)? Are there some `build.sbt` configuration settings available to do that? Ideally, I don't want to have another tool/dependency just to get rid of those 2 lines.

Following is a list of things I have tried:

- Set run logLevel to Warn
- Set Global logLevel to Warn
- Set `-Dsbt.log.noformat=true`

The workaround that I am currently using:
Copy the `java` invocation that `sbt` generates (by doing `ps` or `top`) as a result of doing `fork in run := true` and manually run that `java` command directly on the command line.

It would be much cleaner if `sbt` could be told not to print those lines.

- Scala version: 2.9.1
- SBT version: 0.11.1

Comment: Do you always start your application like this? sbt is a build tool and not an application runner. If I am right with my assumption I would suggest you to instead build and package your application and run it with `scala.

Comment: Thanks @drexin yes I realized there are better ways to fire it up. I am now using [one-jar](https://github.com/sbt/sbt-onejar). Pretty cool and does exactly what I've been wanting to do: simple and straightforward invocation post development.

Answer (score 17):

### sbt 1.x, sbt 0.13.13+

Use `-warn` or `-error`. See [Fixes with compatibility implications for sbt 0.13.13 release](https://github.com/sbt/sbt/blob/1.0.x/notes/0.13.13.markdown#fixes-with-compatibility-implications):

> it is strongly encouraged to migrate to the single hyphen options: `-error`, `-warn`, `-info`, and `-debug`

### sbt 0.13.1

To disable `info` messages run SBT with `--warn` or `--error` command line options.

To disable `[success]` messages set `showSuccess` to `false`.

Bringing it all together, it gives you the following options:

- On command line use the following:

  ```
    $ sbt --error 'set showSuccess := false' run
  ```
- In `build.sbt` add `showSuccess := false`

  ```
    $ cat build.sbt
    showSuccess := false
  ```

and execute `sbt --error run`.

Comment: That's my experience as well. No longer works at sbt 1.0.2.

Comment: Should work again in sbt 1.1.2: [fix](https://github.com/sbt/sbt/pull/4036)

Comment: I'm still getting `[info]` messages in 1.5.5

Comment: Specifically, I'm still seeing `[info]` when doing `~run` after `sbt`. If I do `sbt run` it works as described in this answer.

Answer (score 7):

As Jacek mentioned in his response, in `build.sbt` you can add `showSuccess := false` to suppress the `[success]` message.  To suppress the `[info]` message, I'd set the logLevel to `Level.Warn` for the `run` configuration only.  Putting it together, you want to add these lines to `build.sbt`:

```
showSuccess := false

logLevel in run := Level.Warn
```

Answer (score 4):

You should be able to get rid of the "Set current project" line by adding this to your `build.sbt` file:

```
onLoadMessage := ""
```

Answer (score 1):

This is an old question that comes up at top of web searches, but gives the wrong answer. After [this change](https://github.com/sbt/sbt/issues/840) was recently merged, the prescribed way to suppress interactive noise is by passing two flags to sbt:

```
sbt -batch -error ...
```

Works for me in `sbt` 1.8.0