# How to suppress info messages in sbt [1.0.0,1.0.4]?

Tags: sbt

This is related to "[How to suppress info and success messages in sbt?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9968300/how-to-suppress-info-and-success-messages-in-sbt)", but that was for a previous version.

Back in sbt 0.13.x, and currently [on the sbt 1.x website](https://github.com/sbt/website/blob/8490bea95f256ae61e86eeac9dee0151bad9f1f3/src/reference/04-Howto/06-Howto-Logging.md#change-the-logging-level-globally), it says that using "`--` before the logging level" can "set the logging level before any commands are executed on startup". Meanwhile, the referenced SO post points to a [change](https://github.com/sbt/sbt/blob/8db6cd7a9e5810024cc304ef8ef7a5683b0ebe28/notes/0.13.13.markdown#fixes-with-compatibility-implications) that says "it is strongly encouraged to migrate to the single hyphen options: `-error`, `-warn`, `-info`, and `-debug`".

Neither syntax `--error` nor `-error` seem to quiet sbt. Following the website documentation syntax:

```
mkdir project
echo 'sbt.version=1.0.4' > project/build.properties
sbt sbtVersion --error
```

This produced a bunch of messages, culminating with:

> [info] 1.0.4
>   [warn] The `-` command is deprecated in favor of `onFailure` and will be removed in 0.14.0

Switching to `sbt sbtVersion -error` with a single dash removed the warning, but still had the other `[info]` lines.

FYI switching the version to `0.13.16` doesn't output anything, as I would expect.

Is there a new way in sbt 1.x to suppress messages? I'm guessing this is a bug but asking here just in case following the [contribution guidelines](https://github.com/sbt/sbt/blob/8db6cd7a9e5810024cc304ef8ef7a5683b0ebe28/CONTRIBUTING.md#where-to-get-help-andor-file-a-bug-report).

Edit: [Issue #3849](https://github.com/sbt/sbt/issues/3849) mentioning 1.1.0-RC4 was opened earlier today, and I'm assuming it's the same for the 1.0.x series.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yup. I think it's a [bug](https://github.com/sbt/sbt/issues/3849) around logging.

**Update:** it has been fixed in [sbt 1.1.2](https://developer.lightbend.com/blog/2018-03-26-sbt-1-1-2-hotfix/) ([fix](https://github.com/sbt/sbt/pull/4036)).