# Limit output with scala on IntelliJ

Tags: scala, intellij-idea

I am using IntelliJ IDEA for Scala. When I write a block of Scala code, I build the project and execute it. At the bottom window of intellij you can see the code running.

In the output window below I will get a line of output that looks like:

> 18/03/27 15:07:31 INFO SparkContext: Created broadcast 132 from broadcast at LogisticRegression.scala:1879

All in RED text. There are hundreds of output lines in red text.
I am only interested in seeing the white text. For example:

```
println("My white text")
```

How do I hide this information overkill in intellij?
There is too much info in the output window at the bottom. Where are the options in intellij to curtail what is being output?

I understand this info will be useful if I am debugging and looking for answers as to why something isn't working.
But for now, its completely in the way and annoying.

Any help would be great.

Comment: Have you tried something like this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/20817292/8230810

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems like you are you using spark, if so you can set the `log level`

```
import org.apache.log4j.Level
import org.apache.log4j.{Level, Logger}

Logger.getLogger("org").setLevel(Level.OFF)
Logger.getLogger("akka").setLevel(Level.OFF)
```

Or inside your spark folder find `conf/log4j.properties` and update the `log4j.rootCategory` to

```
log4j.rootCategory=INFO, console
```

Hope this helps

Comment: it's not a great idea to code the logging level into the app as it will require a redeploy to change those settings.

Comment: Yeah, that's correct, but to run small spark programs to test from the ide won't have any problems.

Comment: I have found a file called: log4j.properties.template   Do I change its name to something else?

Comment: Yeah change the file name to `log4j.properties`

Comment: Seems to have cut the amount of red messages appearing dramatically. Its a lot more manageable now. I thought the issue was with IntelliJ, but it wasn't. It was obviously feeding the info to spark, and what was appearing in the window was coming from a local install of spark, hence java.

Comment: yeah that was from the spark log.:)

Answer (score 1):

this is a function of the logging framework being used by the dependencies you've included in your program.

Spark uses log4j to log, details here: https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/configuration.html#configuring-logging

Essentially, you need to tell the logger what messages to print using the log4j.prooerties file.